# How to embed a spotify track in WPF Application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to embed a spotify track (for example: https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/5sICkBXVmaCQk5aISGR3x1)
in my WPF Application.

I am using the WebBrowser:
`<WebBrowser Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" x:Name="webBrowser1"  />`
So far I tried this:
`webBrowser1.Navigate("https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/5sICkBXVmaCQk5aISGR3x1");`
but it doesn't work.